# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working in React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I have recently finished a React site. I have set up an integration with SendGrid to receive emails. Unfortunately, when I test the email feature on localhost:3000, I get an error. It is the standard Access-Control error that many face. What confuses me is that despite using res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*'), it still will not work.

If I do not change anything, will emails send if I properly deploy this website?

Below is my code.

App.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');

const sendGrid = require('@sendGrid/mail');


const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(cors());

app.use((req, res, next) => {
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE');
    res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization');
    next();
});

app.get('/api', (req, res, next) => {
    res.send('API Status: Running')
});

app.post('/api', (req, res, next) => {

    sendGrid.setApiKey('');
    const msg = {
        to: '',
        from: req.body.email,
        subject: 'Website Contact',
        text: req.body.message

    }

    sendGrid.send(msg)
        .then(result => {

            res.status(200).json({
                success: true
            });

        })
        .catch(err => {

            console.log('error', err);
            res.status(401).json({
                success: false
            });

        });

});

app.listen(3030, '0.0.0.0');
```

ContactPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

import Form from 'react-bootstrap/Form';
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

import Content from '../components/Content';
import Hero from '../components/Hero';
import Axios from 'axios';

class ContactPage extends React.Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            name: '',
            email: '',
            message: '',
            disabled: false,
            emailSent: null,
        }
    }

    handleChange = (event) => {
        console.log(event);

        const target = event.target;
        const value = target.type === 'checkbox' ? target.checked : target.value;
        const name = target.name;

        this.setState({
            [name]: value
        })
    }

    handleSubmit = (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        this.setState({
            disabled: true,
            emailSent: true
        });

        Axios.post('http://localhost:3030/api/email', this.state)
            .then(res => {
                if (res.data.success) {
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: true
                    });
                } else {
                    this.setState({
                        disabled: false,
                        emailSent: false
                    });
                }
            })
            .catch(err => {
                this.setState({
                    disabled: false,
                    emailSent: false
                });
            })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Hero title={this.props.title}></Hero>

                <Content>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor='full-name'>Full Name</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                id="full-name"
                                name="name"
                                type="text"
                                value={this.state.name}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor='email'>Email</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                id="email"
                                name="email"
                                type="email"
                                value={this.state.email}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group>
                            <Form.Label htmlFor='message'>Message</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control
                                id="message"
                                name="message"
                                as="textarea"
                                rows="3"
                                value={this.state.message}
                                onChange={this.handleChange}
                            />
                        </Form.Group>
                        <br></br>


                        <Button className="d-inline-block" variant="primary" type="submit" disabled={this.state.disabled}>
                            Send
                        </Button>


                        {this.state.emailSent === true && <p className="d-inline success-msg">Email Sent</p>}
                        {this.state.emailSent === false && <p className="d-inline err-msg">Email Not Sent</p>}
                    </Form>
                </Content>
            </div>
        );
    }

}

export default ContactPage;
```

Comment: If you use `app.use(cors())`, you don't need to manually set the `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers

Comment: _"It is the standard Access-Control error that many face"_... there is no **standard** here. What **exactly** is the error message?

Comment: Is the browser doing an OPTIONS request before the real request? que the Netwok tab in deb tools. Try doing `res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, DELETE, OPTIONS');`, I had some issues because of not considering the OPTIONS method requests before and if the server fails it may appear as a `cors` error in the browser when it's actually an issue handling the request.

Comment: @arieljuod the `cors` middleware should already take care of pre-flight request configuration